# replacing a range outlet

Tags: electrical

I am replacing the range in my kitchen with a free standing range.  The old range was a electric cook top with a separate wall oven. The old oven and stovetop were connected to a breaker box behind the cabinet which was connected to a junction box near the floor.  I removed the breaker and junction box and all wiring.  Now all I have coming through the floor is the main wiring. There are 3 wires:red, black and white, no ground.  Do I attach a 3 prong recepticle to this or does it have to be 4 prong?  There is no ground wire.  And get a 3 prong cord for my stove?  Will it be grounded?  Sometimes I would receive a slight shock from the stove if I touched the sink at the same time.  I was told that the stovetop was going bad.

Answer (score 1):

There is a provision in the National Electrical Code that will allow a 3-wire installation, in situations where there is existing wiring (250.140 exception). You should be fine to install a three prong receptacle, and use a three prong range cord.

There should be special instructions in the manufacturer's installation instructions that are included with the range, that will specify exactly how to attach the 3-wire cord.

If you're really concerned about it, or want to update to follow modern code. You could install a new 3-wire with ground cable, and use 4-prong receptacle and cord.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 250 Grounding and Bonding
>
> **250.140 Frames of Ranges and Clothes Dryers.** Frames
>   of electric ranges, wall-mounted ovens, counter-mounted
>   cooking units, clothes dryers, and outlet or junction boxes
>   that are part of the circuit for these appliances shall be
>   connected to the equipment grounding conductor in the
>   manner specified by 250.134 or 250.138.
>
> ***Exception:*** For existing branch-circuit installations only
>   where an equipment grounding conductor is not present in
>   the outlet or junction box, the frames of electric ranges,
>   wall-mounted ovens, counter-mounted cooking units,
>   clothes dryers, and outlet or junction boxes that are part of
>   the circuit for these appliances shall be permitted to be
>   connected to the grounded circuit conductor if all the following
>   conditions are met.
>
> *(1) The supply circuit is 120/240-volt, single-phase,
>   3-wire; or 208Y/120-volt derived from a 3-phase,
>   4-wire, wye-connected system.*
>
> *(2) The grounded conductor is not smaller than 10 AWG
>   copper or 8 AWG aluminum.*
>
> *(3) The grounded conductor is insulated, or the grounded
>   conductor is uninsulated and part of a Type SE serviceentrance
>   cable and the branch circuit originates at the
>   service equipment.*
>
> *(4) Grounding contacts of receptacles furnished as part of
>   the equipment are bonded to the equipment.*

Comment: Thanks.  I know replacing the wire would be best, but it runs throught the ceiling joist of my finished basement.  Just want to be safe,  An electrician  told me to put on a 4 prong recepticle and buy a 4 prong cord for the new stove.  I was concerned about the grounding, so I just wanted to check.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use that electrician to do any work on the house...  What would the 4th prong go to?